# Why does namespaces/imports work differently between c# and Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, namespaces

Co-worker and I have noticed something strange with Razor and importing namespaces.

Here is our test class we'll try accessing from both a c# file and a Razor view.

```
namespace test
{
    public class c1 {}
}

namespace test.sub
{
    public class c2 {}
}
```

This is a sample of our c# code.

```
using test;

namespace test
{
    public class testbed
    {
        testbed()
        {
            c1 o1 = new c1();                   //works
            test.sub.c2 o2 = new test.sub.c2(); //works
            sub.c2 o3 = new sub.c2();           //works
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample of our Razor code. the "sub" namespace is not accessible.

```
@using test
@(new c1())          @* Works *@
@(new test.sub.c2()) @* Works *@
@(new sub.c2())      @* Cannot be seen *@
```

Does anyone have an explanation for why this it works in our class files but not in our views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sub.c2` works in your code because your are in namespace "test". Change the namespace to titi and you'll see it won't work

```
namespace titi
{
    using test;

    public class testbed
    {
        testbed()
        {
            c1 o1 = new c1();                   //works
            test.sub.c2 o2 = new test.sub.c2(); //works
            sub.c2 o3 = new sub.c2();           //don't work
        }
    }
}

namespace test
{
    using test;

    public class testbed
    {
        testbed()
        {
            c1 o1 = new c1();                   //works
            test.sub.c2 o2 = new test.sub.c2(); //works
            sub.c2 o3 = new sub.c2();           //works because your are in namespace *test*
        }
    }
}
```

Your razor code is in another namespace (eg. different from `test`) so `sub.c2` does not work.

Comment: Our focus is to try and understand why the razor section doesn't work. The c# code we work with works exactly as expected. I can try and clarify my question if needed.

Comment: Razor code is not defined within a namespace. It imports the `test` namespace, but the key difference is the `namespace` keyword in your C# code.

Comment: @meziantou We've tested your code and it is not solving the issue we are seeing. What's missing in your sample is the using statement `using test;` which will make `c1 o1 = new c1()`. I think Im missing something in my explanation or in my question which makes your work not focused on our problem, sorry about that. So if you add the using statment you'll see the only thing that will not work is `sub.c2 o3 = new sub.c2();`

Comment: I understand the reason why it doesn't work inside of razor, thanks!.
I don't understand that if we include a using statement why we don't have access to the "sub" parts of it. `sub.c2 o3 = new sub.c2();` Is this intended by design?  [Example Code](http://imgur.com/XYYgmAn).

Comment: A using-namespace-directive imports the types contained in the given namespace, but specifically does not import nested namespaces.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664766(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thank you @meziantou for your patience and answers.